# Zend_Amf headers

Tags: php, zend-framework, amf, zend-amf

I'm using charles proxy to debug a zend amf response. The headers are coming back as:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 29 Aug 2009 10:04:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8k DAV/2 PHP/5.3.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Should the content type be application/x-amf.

Does apache need something special to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if you have called header() in your php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers should be x-amf. Something in my php script was corrupting the output. The charles proxy item should have an 'A' icon. I didn't have to add anything in Apache.